# Spring Data Redis + LettuceConnectionFactory + SSL enabled ElastiCache Cluster

Tags: spring-data-redis, amazon-elasticache

Looking for any examples connecting to ElastiCache redis ssl enabled cluster via lettuceConnectionFactory of spring data redis. Any suggestions ?